# Why can't I use the Match method on an array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby, parsing, iterator

I need to iterate and parse 108 lines from a file and then sort them into 3 different hashes. (In one iterator.) (In Ruby)

I have the file loaded into the program and into the array I need to parse. When I try to make the iterator anyway I try to use the Regex Match command I get an error abut the unknown method. Is as simple that I can't use that method on a array?

```
lines = File.readlines('access_log')

lines.each.match(/^([:\d\.]+) .*\[.*\].*\"[A-Z]+ *(.+) HTTP/)
```

This and every other way I have tried to use the match method it hasn't worked. 
This also doesn't anything for the hash, as I haven't done that yet.

```
/^([:\d\.]+) .*\[.*\].*\"[A-Z]+ *(.+) HTTP/.match(lines)
```

Have also tried this, but the error output appears that you cant run it on only the array. I beilive this is where I would need to tie the iterator in, but I'm stumped.

Comment: _"Why can't I use the Match method on an array?"_ – because `Array` doesn't have a `match` method. Neither does `Enumerator` (the result of `Array#each`). Among Ruby's core classes, only `Symbol`, `String` and `Regexp` respond to `match`. And none of them takes an array as its argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what's happening is that what readlines does is it slurps the entire text file.

So you have an array with the content of the textfile separated by a newline(and the newline is kept in every string in the array).

After that, you're doing lines.each, which brings out an enumerator. Then you're calling .match on the enumerator instead of the string itself

The proper way to do this would be

```
lines.each { |line| line.match(/^([:\d\.]+) .*\[.*\].*\"[A-Z]+ *(.+) HTTP/) }
```

However, the above actually won't do anything because all you're doing is iterating against each element and checking if it matches the REGEX.If you want it to actually do something, try...

```
  matches = lines.map { |line| line.match(/^([:\d\.]+) .*\[.*\].*\"[A-Z]+ *(.+) HTTP/) }
```

Remember that the match method only works on strings. If match matches something, it returns an object of the class MatchData, else if it doesn't match anything-- nil.

Comment: So after that using ``` matches = lines.map{...} ``` I would need to figure out how to put that information into my three hashes right? Because the MatchData is saved in the matches variable. Or would it be better to have three different match variables with different regular expressions to then put into the hashes?

Comment: Yeah! That's pretty much it. Ask more questions if you need more help! I'm not particularly sure of what you're trying to accomplish, though. What kind of information are you trying to parse into 3 different hashes?

Comment: So the basis is that I am trying to sort the IP, the URL, and the HTTP codes into their respective hashes and count the number for each. The other problem that I have is getting the arrays data into the hash. I don't think the inject command would work in this case because its a different type of data.

Comment: Can I see an example of the 'access_log' file you're slurping? Sorry if my responses are slow, I'm studying right now and I take breaks every 30 minutes.

Comment: One line of the data looks like this: 
192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:23 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4897 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"

Comment: Oh man, that's rough. Is there an example of a URL In that line? Are all of the lines in the same format? Are you allowed to use gems?

Comment: That was a poor example, That one did not have a URL attached to it. All of the lines are in the same format luckily. I do not know what a gem is (very new to programing).

Better Example:

192.168.1.142 - - [30/Sep/2016:16:18:24 -0400] "GET /noindex/css/fonts/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 239 "http://optiplex360/noindex/css/open-sans.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"